# Packaging src/test into a jar in a sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt

In a sbt project, The standard source locations for testing are:

Scala sources in `src/test/scala/`

Java sources in `src/test/java/`

Those test files are not packaged when I run `sbt package`

I want to copy the packaged jar to a remote machine to run the test.

Is there a way to let sbt include test resources in the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `sbt test:package` instead. This will produce a separate jar from the main one, so don't forget to copy both (and the test dependencies); if you want to have just one jar to manage, you can use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and run `sbt test:assembly`.

Answer (score 0):

Test to include: % "compile->test" in your sbt in the line that you declare the test . Probably something like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "scalacheck" % "1.9" % "test"
```

will be something like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "scalacheck" % "1.9" % "compile->test"
```

I think you will need "assembly" instead of package to include Test library but I not sure about this point.

Comment: No, that's an answer to an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative to explicitly running test:package.
In the sbt, for the project definition , you update the packageBin settings as given below.

project
.settings(fullClasspath in Compile := (fullClasspath in Test).value )
.settings(packageBin in Compile := (packageBin in Test).value)

Once this is done  , project-tests.jar will be created.